# Html encoding in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-parsing

I have a search grid and when I select any row and close it the values get mapped to textboxes in aspx form. Issue is evrytime I have a value like `' ab & cd'` it gets mapped as `' ab &amp; cd'`

i am finding the value as follows in the click event of tr

```
$(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").html();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this** html() gets the html code. and .text() function returns only text visible.

```
$(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

The raw JavaScript [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/DOM/window.unescape) function can be used for this as follows:

```
var content = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").html();
var unescapedContent = unescape(content);
```